# The temperature of a metal plate is given by $f(x,y)=\frac{150}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$. Find the R.O.C of the temperature at the point $(8,4)$...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, chain-rule

The temperature of  a metal plate is given by $f(x,y)=\frac{150}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$. Find the rate of change of the temperature at the point $(8,4)$, in the direction towards the point $(7,2)$

Right now I have that $\triangledown f(x,y)=\langle\frac{-150x}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \frac{-150y}{(x^2+y^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}} \rangle$.

Next, I have $\triangledown f(8,4)=\langle\frac{-400}{243}$, $\frac{-200}{243}\rangle$.

From here I'm not sure what to do with the "direction toward $(7,2)$".

Comment: Do you know the definition of a directional derivative?

Comment: Yes, so would I use the $lim_t\to 0$

Comment: In this case, $(7,2)$ is not a vector.

Comment: How do you find the vector from one point toward another?

Comment: From $D_uf(8,4)$? I know how to find this with a vector, but the direction is not $(7,2)$

Comment: What is the vector that points from (8, 4) to (7, 2)? That's the direction you want.

Comment: Would it be $\langle 1,2 \rangle$

Comment: Other way around. You want (8, 4) + X = (7, 2), so X should be (8, 4) - (7, 2) = (-1, -2).

Comment: One thing to be watchful about: "vector" $\ne$ "direction". Instead "vector" $=$ "direction and magnitude". They are asking for the rate-of-change in the *direction* of $(7,2)$, not the rate-of-change with respect to the vector to $(7,2)$. You need to take the magnitude out of it.